# jquery animate doesnt work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

im trying to animate the width of a table, so the content gets "closed" and "opened". So I manipulate the right and left gap:

```
   $(".gaps").animate({width:"35%"},'slow', function(){      
     $(".gaps").animate({width: "10%"},'slow');
     $("#content").fadeIn();
   });
```

but somehow, its not animating linear. First 10% to 35% works fine, but the width jumps to over 100 at the start of the 10%-animation, so the content is jumping around. I tried some things like "width: "-=25%"", but even that didnt work. Am i having some other problems, dont i just see the obvious?

Thanks!

Comment: could i f.e. set the start and end-value of the animation?

Comment: Sorry, but tables just do not behave nicely when it comes to animating sizes. Depending on what you are trying to do you might want to wrap your table with to divs: the inner one with static size and the outer one width overflow:hidden and then try to animate the outer one.

Comment: Thanks! kinda worked :)

Comment: :-) - Just because I already finished it - here is the jsfiddle for that: http://jsfiddle.net/mgwo9axL/

Answer (score 0):

To finish this i will add the answer from the comments:

Sorry, but tables just do not behave nicely when it comes to animating sizes. Depending on what you are trying to do you might want to wrap your table with to divs: the inner one with static size and the outer one width overflow:hidden and then try to animate the outer one.

```
<div style="overflow:hidden; background:red;" class="animateMe">
    <div style="width:300px;">
       <table>...</table>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mgwo9axL